# How can I find the name of my Network Interface

Tags: networking, python, ethernet, network-interface

I have a project that requires me to scan the local network.

I found a program on the internet that allows the local network scanner condition, but I brought the gold @ IP argument in my network program must be turned the machine alone after two minutes.

So I determined a program from my PC IP and mask can give me the class CIDR (192.168.1.123/24), but to find this result I have to give the name of the network interface that my pc is connected (ie: wlan0, eth0 or eth1) to.

**Q:** Is there a method to find the name of the interface without the whole list as `ifconfig` does?

Comment: How about `route`? Just grab the default and that will tell you. At least I think you're asking what is the default interface..

Comment: Could you explain why you don't want to use `ifconfig`? That is the right tool for the job.

Comment: @terdon see the original question...it's an assignment that's why `ifconfig` can't be used. I just don't know if the user wants a list of all of the interfaces or just the default route interface. As we know, eth1 can exist even if it is the only card on the system, if there are 100 cards, or the default route and that's why I flagged it. I think you've cleared it up though.

Comment: @kaio, please stop adding explanations in comments. You need to explain exactly what you need in the body of your question. Please [edit] and explain exactly what you need and what limitations you have.

Comment: I need to create a program that gives me the name of the interface to which I am connected wlan0 or eth0 or eth1 without all as both ifconfig gives me

Comment: As I said, don't add stuff in comments, [edit] your question instead. Comments can be deleted without warning and are hard to read and easy to miss. Explain why you can't use `ifconfig`, explain what else you need (you mentioned scanning and netmask).

Answer (score 3):

Get the default route, and catch the interface column:

```
nicolas@host:~$ ip route list | grep default | awk '{print $5} '
wlan0
```

Comment: `awk '/default/ {print $5}' <(ip route)`

Comment: We need to go deeper: `awk '/def/ {print $5}' <(ip r)` :). My answer had a more explanatory approach, using long parameters.

Comment: I was pointing out that using `grep` with `awk` is redundant and an unnecessary process...

Comment: GNU `grep` can do the whole thing: `ip r | grep -oP '^def.*\Keth.'`

Comment: Modern ip-route has a "default" selector: `ip route list default | awk '$0=$5'`

Answer (score 2):

List the content of the directory `/sys/class/net/`. Each file in there corresponds to one interface. According to your question, you should find at least one file starting with `eth`.

Comment: thanks user236012 for your answer but when i open this file I find the three interfaces eth0 and waln0 l0 gold I am connected via wifi so that interests me is wlan0 in this case and in other cases I can find in this file and eth0 eth1 or so I am connected via eth1 my problem how can I recovered that which I am connected interface .

Comment: [Punctuation saves lives](https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#q=punctuation+saves+lives)

Comment: Yes, but if I find eth1 and eth0 how I can learn from both the interface with which the PC is connected

Comment: In first place, you just wanted to know what the name of the wired interface was. Didn't read your edit, sorry!